# Is it possible to override BakeTasks in a plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want Bake to add a custom TimestampBehavior to every table which has the fields created_at, modified_at, proved_at. I also want to remove the Validators for these fields.
Whether a model is added the TimestampBehavior is programmed in Bake/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php. I don't want to edit the file in the vendor folder, because my file might be overridden by an update.

Moving the file to my plugins folder doesn't work since i get the error message "class ModelTask is already defined".

Is it possible to extend the ModelTask somehow or to use a custom ModelTask.php in my plugins folder for bake to achieve my goal?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Moving the file to my plugins folder doesn't work since i get the error message "class ModelTask is already defined".

It doesn't work because you probably haven't changed the namespace. Fix the namespace to the one the plugin uses and you're done. You can even extend classes of the same name by using `uses Foo as Bar` and then `Foo extends Bar`.